# How to use github webhooks on Gerrithub

Tags: github, gerrithub.io

I have a project on Github with some 3rd party services working with WebHook, something like travis, codefactor, deepscan, etc...
I would like to know how to use these services on Gerrithub to act as a verifier.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to setup your webhook per project as specified in [this](https://review.gerrithub.io/plugins/webhooks/Documentation/config.md) documentation.

> The webhooks plugin’s per project configuration is stored in the webhooks.config 
>    file in project’s refs/meta/config branch.

Comment: Hello Sir, how to confirm a webhook is triggerd?Is there any log info and where is it please.